# Can the division rings appearing in the Wedderburn-Artin theorem be isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra, division-ring

I am asking because I was thinking about this problem:

> Can we determine the simple modules of a semisimple ring from its product decomposition given by the Wedderburn-Artin theorem?

Let me state the theorem first

> **Thm (Wedderburn-Artin)** Let $R$ be a left semisimple ring. Then $R\cong M_{n_1}(D_1)\times\cdots\times M_{n_r}(D_r)$ for division rings $D_i$ and the pairs $(n_i,D_i)$ are uniquely determined. Moreover, there are exactly $r$ isomorphism classes of simple $R$-modules.

Now suppose the pairs $(n_i,D_i)$ are distinct. Then their simple modules are respectively $V_i=D_i^{n_i}$ and are non isomorphic to each other. Note that they are also simple over $R$ (by projecting $R$ to $M_{n_i}(D_i)$ first and then act on the modules). Since they are nonisomorphic, by the Wedderburn-Artin theorem they are exactly all the simple modules of $R$ up to isomorphism.

However, suppose $(n_i,D_i)=(n_j,D_j)$ for some $i\neq j$. Then there are less than $r$ simple modules obtained as above. How can we determine the simple modules from the decomposition now? Or can such case not happen at all?

Comment: Have you thought about the simplest case $R=F\times F$ where $F$ is a field?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I did. If what I have written is correct, then $F$ as a one-dimensional vector space is a sinmple $R$-module, with scalar multiplication given by left multiplication by the first copy of $F$ in $R$. But there should be 2 nonisomorphic simple $R$-modules. What is the other one? I think I may have misunderstood something. I'd appreciated it if you can point it out.

Comment: I see two non-isomorphic simple $R$-modules: one annihilated by $(1,0)$ and the other by $(0,1)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Fair point! Are you saying that if we take two copies of $F$, say $F_1,F_2$, and make $F_1$ a simple $R$-module by first projecting $R$ onto its first $F$ component and then act on $F_1$ by multiplication. Now we do the same for $F_2$ but we project $R$ onto the second component this time. So even though $F_1,\ F_2$ are seemingly isomorphic but they are really not as $R$-modules. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: That's right: the two actions of $R$ of $F$ are **different**.

Comment: @trisct please consider writing up what you learned as a self-answer, since the other person has apparently passed on helping via a solution.  Please don’t let this question linger on unanswered if you already have a resolution. Thanks.